# What is the difference (if any) between “tee < infile > outfile” and “cat infile | tee > outfile”?

Tags: bash, performance, cat, time, tee

I obtained the following:

```
$ time $(tee < infile > outfile)
real 0m14.721s
user 0m0.094s
sys 0m2.629s

$ time $(cat infile | tee > outfile)
real 0m8.931s
user 0m0.123s
sys 0m3.168
```

Is that difference just owing to redirection/piping,
or is there something else going on here?

Running them a second time gave the following:

```
$ time $(tee < infile > outfile)
real 0m11.558
user 0m0.113s
sys 0m2.691s

$ time $(cat infile | tee > outfile)
real 0m8.822s
user 0m0.120s
sys 0m3.125s
```

P.S. Both `infile` and `outfile` were MP4 files, cached in RAM;
if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note: no need for `$()` it will result in output being thrown away, and `time` does not need it. `()` would be good though.

Comment: You just edited the commands, but leave the timings for the old commands. ☹ (-1)

Comment: .. because that was the result I obtained ... I had made the mistake in the body.

Comment: I did not believe you so, I have just repeated the experiment. The one with `cat` is slower. I still don't believe you.

Comment: Why do you time the result of executing the output of those commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Overcome by events): 
<sub><del>The examples are not the same as in the title.</del></sub>

## For the question in the title.

The version with `cat` will be marginally slower.

---

[Editorial note:
the remainder of this answer is based on an earlier version of the question,
which contained a typo. 
The question has been edited, so the following is no longer relevant.]

## For the question in the body

The first command is writing two files. This is why is is slower.
The second is starting an extra process (`cat`), but this is a small slowdown compared to writing extra file.

The second run is faster, probably, because the read is cached.

## Explanation

`tee < infile tee > outfile` is functionally equivalent, but faster than `cat infile | tee tee > outfile`, whereas `tee > outfile` is not. 
The first two produce two files, the 3rd produces one, so will be faster.

Comment: Look again `tee > outfile` it only has **one** output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Sorry, I had written it wrongly; but I checked my history - the title is what I meant.